# liferay popup dispalying tthe same content as its render page

Tags: liferay

I have a popup which show the same page from which it was clicked . I have redirected it to another jsp but it does not show that jsp page but instead shows the same jsap page in the jsp .Below is the code . Thanks in advance

**All the code below is in view.jsp**

```
 <portlet:defineObjects />

 <script type="text/javascript">
  var dialog2
  function Popupdisplay1(url,flr){
   alert(url);
   AUI().use('aui-dialog', 'aui-io', function(A) {
     alert("reached here inside popup");
     dialog2 = new A.Dialog({
    align:Liferay.Util.Window.ALIGN_CENTER,
    title: 'My PopUp',
    centered: true,
    modal: true,
    width: 550,
    height: 400,
    id: 'alert',
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    }).plug(A.Plugin.IO, {uri: url}).render();
 });

}



</script>
<portlet:renderURL var="contractURL" windowState=<%=LiferayWindowState.EXCLUSIVE.toString()%>">
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="" />
</portlet:renderURL>



<td><input class="notify" type="button"     value="Notify"onclick="Popupdisplay1('<%=contractURL.toString()%>')"></td>
```

Comment: Why jspPage param is empty? Dont you want to open up a differnte page within the popup?

Comment: yes i had given "/html/popup.jsp" but still it does not work !!

Comment: this usually happen when your targeted page is not found

Comment: <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/popup.jsp" /></portlet:renderURL>

Comment: i have have given this code for param. I had forgot to mention earlier. . Still its showing the same page in the pop up !!

Comment: What is the result if you try to access the generated URL?